# Remove . from decimal ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a decimal column `price`. I got two prices: `10.00` and `11.50`

I need to transform

`10.00` into `1000`

`11.50`into `1150`

How I can do that in controller?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just multiply the number by `100` and then do [to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) on the result:

```
f = 10.0
n = (f * 100).to_i
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's a string:

`"10.00".gsub(".", "")`

If it's a decimal number

`(10.00 * 100).to_i` == 1000

(10.00).to_floor

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string, replace dot, convert to int

```
my_number = 10.56
my_number_without_decimal_point = my_number.to_s().gsub(".", "").to_i()
puts "#{my_number_without_decimal_point}"
```

prints 1056